# Form from a Contact Form wont Submit

Tags: html, forms

Can someone see if they know why My form code is not working. Its displays fine on my website, but nothing will happen when I press submit. I was wondering if there is something Im missing in my form?

```
<form method="post" name="CForm" action="form.php" onsubmit="return ValidateCForm();"> 
    <div class="fieldHolder">
        <input class="textInput" type="text" name="name" size="20" value="Name" onfocus=" if (this.value == 'Name' ) { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='Name';} ">
    </div> 
    <div class="fieldHolder">
        <input class="textInput" type="text" name="email" size="20" value="Email" onfocus=" if (this.value == 'Email' )  this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='Email';} ">
    </div> 
    <div class="fieldHolder">
        <input class="textInput" type="text" name="Phone" size="20" value="Phone" onfocus=" if (this.value == 'Phone' ) { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='Phone';} ">
    </div> 
    <div class="fieldHolder">
        <textarea class="textarea" name="comments" id="textarea-field" onfocus=" if (this.value == 'How can we help you?') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='How can we help you?';} ">How can we help you?</textarea>
    </div>  
    <div class="code floatleft">Security Question :</div> <div class="code floatleft">3 + 10 = ?</div>  
    <div class="fieldHolder">
        <input class="textInput" id="security_code" name="security_code" type="text" value="Enter Answer" onfocus=" if (this.value == 'Enter Answer' ) { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='Enter Answer';} "><br>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="formname" value="13">        
    <input type="submit" class="expand radius" name="Submit" value="Submit" alt="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I assume there is an error with `ValidateCForm`, could you post that code for that too.

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors in your console? Can you remove the onsubmit javascript function and check what happens?

Answer (score 0):

This line is missing a starting bracket:

```
<input class="textInput" type="text" name="email" size="20" value="Email" onfocus=" if (this.value == 'Email' )  this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='Email';} ">
```

At this area: `if (this.value == 'Email' )  this.value = ''; }`

Change it to this:

```
<input class="textInput" type="text" name="email" size="20" value="Email" onfocus=" if (this.value == 'Email' ) { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='Email';} ">
```